# Solar Micro-inverter: Energy Destination

Tags: electrical-engineering

I have just started looking at the concept of solar panels with individual micro-inverters.

Let’s say we have a simple setup of a single solar panel with its own micro-inverter that synchronizes with the grid at my breaker box.

Below is how I perceive energy would flow. I am curious if someone with expertise in synchronized AC systems can confirm this as correct or explain what I have wrong in my thinking.

It seems that if the micro-inverter power inserted is small in relation to total power consumption, the net impedance of the house AC load would effectively look higher to the grid, reducing power coming in from the grid.

If the house load should drop significantly and/or the instantaneous power production from the micro-inverter is greater than the energy demand, then power would appear to flow out to the grid.

Is this correct?

Best regards,
Bruce

Answer (score 1):

If the house presents zero load, then the inverter injects to the grid.

If the house presents a load then the power produced by the inverter will contribute to powering that load up to its max possible output at that time, the rest will come from the grid.

Comment: Thanks Mike … so the micro-inverter instantaneously figures what the maximum power point of the solar panel is and, knowing it is say 289 watts (deliverable), it adjusts its synchronized inverter drive voltage (against whatever the house voltage is currently) to push x amps of current into the house wiring to equal what the panel’s production is. Correct?

Comment: My hat’s off to the control systems designer for this type device given the number of permutations, static and dynamic, that are occurring on both sides of the micro-inverter like sunlight variation, house load changes like a 5 ton air conditioner startup, external grid voltage variations and xx other closely coupled micro inverters tweaking their voltages in their optimization algorithms. 

Not to mention lightning hits and wide voltage swings during grid  fault conditions. 

Ditto permutations of a micro-inverter failure. Shorting the panel or grid side are severe issues.

Comment: I’d like to see system reviews from owners that have had these in place with long enough run time to see their real performance. 

The idea of sharing the house power ‘bus’ to distribute on-site generated electric is very clever, but I can see where the devil is in the details.

Comment: Agreed. Basic solar panels are incredibly robust. Set and forget for 20 years. They handle hail, tornados, Cat 5 hurricanes, pretty much anything the house can. I want to see how the electronics survive. I've gone through three (cheap) solar charger converters on my boat in the last 20 years.

Comment: @PhilSweet the 3kW inverter has been fine on our system for 15 years - but unlike yours it was not cheap… but 3 * cheap is likely more expensive than 1 * expensive and it was swiss made.

Comment: Probably the most pertinent part for safety comes down to how are the failure modes handled?  Maybe just simple fusing only on both AC and DC sides?    Is there a circumstance where currents don’t pop fuses, but  pollute the AC waveform so badly they damage motors … fridge, AC, ceiling fans, washer or other freq sensitive devices?     I really want to like this idea as it has so much good potential, but complexity brings lots of permutations. Clever design to create fail-safe modes is in every bodies best interest.

Comment: @BruceCavender buy one, they exist, then test to your heart’s content.

Comment: @BruceCavender Yes, it is trying to push 289 watts onto the grid if that's the amount available. Yes, it's pretty neat and good job on the designers. Considering these devices are designed to be installed at the houses of non-electricians, you can probably stop worrying. As for special fail-safe modes, did you know the inverter is required to shut off if it can't sense external power from the grid? not sure how they do that sensing.

Comment: @user253751 the inverter tries to shift the frequency - if the grid is there then no chance.

Comment: That is interesting. So the inverter is doing a constant ‘micro-hunt’ with its inverter frequency while watching line current.  

If it shifts freq with no change, no grid voltage is present. 

Interesting concept!